# PYTHON: How To Print SSH Key Using Python

Tags: python-2.7, ubuntu-14.04

I've been trying to make a script that can print the Ubuntu SSH key located in ~/.ssh/authorised_keys/

Basically I want the script to print out exactly what cat ~/.ssh/authorised_keys/ would output.

I have tried using subprocess.check_output but it always returns an error.
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What about this ?

```
import os
os.system('cat ~/.ssh/authorised_keys')
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to capture the output to a variable, use `subprocess`. If not, you can use `os.system` as user803422 has mentioned

```
import os, subprocess
path = '~/.ssh/authorized_keys'
cmd = 'cat ' + os.path.expanduser(path)
output = subprocess.Popen(cmd.split(), stdout=subprocess.PIPE)
response = output.communicate()
print (response)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can read the file directly in Python, there is not really a need to use subprocess:

```
import os
print(open(os.path.expanduser('~/.ssh/authorized_keys')).read())
```